# Why a list of one type is not getting converted to another?

Tags: c#

Based on the module name I want to return different lists of different types but problem is that I cannot change the return type for each so I wrote a generic class that has the same properties but it doesn't work that way. How to achieve it.

```
     public List<Models.TasksList> Get(string module)
            {
                //var query= "";
                
                using (var context = new TasksPlanEntities())
                {
                    if (module == "PEMS")
                    {
                        var query = from st in context.PIRTaskLists
                                    select st;
                        return query.ToList<Models.TasksList>();
                else if (module == "PSVMS")
                {
                    var query = from st in context.PSVMS_EnggData
                                select st;
                      return query.ToList<Models.TasksList>();
                }
                    }}
```

TasksList

```
 public class TasksList
    {
        public int OperationID { get; set; }

        public string PIRCode { get; set; }

        public string TaskName { get; set; }

        public string OperationNo { get; set; }

        public string OperationCode { get; set; }

        public string OperationDescription { get; set; }

        //public static explicit operator TasksList(ObjectResult<GetTaskPlans_EPICOR_Result> v)
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}

        public string Resource { get; set; }

        public string NDTResources { get; set; }

        public float Duration { get; set; }

        public string RequiredEquipmentStatus { get; set; }

        public string TimeBaseInterval { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastInspDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime NextInspDate { get; set; }

        public string FunctionalLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

throws error
Cannot implicitly convert to `system.collection.generic.list<Models.TasksList>`

Even though the TasksList class has exactly the same names and all. I tried everything but doesn't work out. Why it is so?

Why this is happening since it's the same structure.

Update:

```
public virtual DbSet<PIRTaskList> PIRTaskLists { get; set; }

 public partial class PIRTaskList
    {
        public int OperationID { get; set; }
        public string PIRCode { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OperationNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Counter { get; set; }
        public string OperationCode { get; set; }
        public string OperationDescription { get; set; }
        public string Resource { get; set; }
        public string NDTResources { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Duration { get; set; }
        public string RequiredEquipmentStatus { get; set; }
        public string TimeBaseInterval { get; set; }
        public string InspectionType { get; set; }
        public string TimeBaseInterval_UOME { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastInspDate { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> NextInspDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> IntermediateDue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ThroughDue { get; set; }
        public string DueDate { get; set; }
        public string GroupStatusID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatusID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EnggDataID { get; set; }
        public string FunctionalLocation { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string CostPerHour_Dollar { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `context.PIRTaskLists` and what is the type of its items?

Comment: Can we assume from your sentence "Even though the TasksList class has exactly the same names and all." (same as what?) that you assume some form of duck typing (when you create a class with exactly the same signature as another class, they are assignable to each other)? That would be a misconception.

Comment: you have to use `.Select` or `.Cast` to convert from one enumerable type to another.

Comment: @Sefe "but in javascript..." ;)

Comment: @DanielA.White Normally, but in this case `.Cast` wouldn't work

Comment: You might have edited the question, but realistically you've only made it more confusing.. now there's another thing (`PSVMS_EnggData`) that looks like it might be wonky, and still no mention of what you were asked for (type of `PIRTaskLists` and definition of the class of its items)..

Comment: OK, so my Person object has a `string Address` property and my Order object has a `string Address` property.. But a Person isn't an Order, just because they happen to have a property with the same name, and I can't turn an Order into a Person just by casting it.. I can use software that will use reflection to look at the two objects and copy data across purely because the property names are the same though. https://automapper.org/

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple, there's nothing that allows a list of `PIRTaskList` to be implicitly converted into a list of `TasksList`. The fact that the classes share the same properties names is irrelevant.

You have *many* options and which one you choose depends entirely on your project/team and knowledge you have about the system that we don't.

- Use `query.Select(x => new TasksList ...).ToList()` to manually transform the items
- Use an implicit/explicit conversion with a `.Select`
- Use a library like AutoMapper
- Use a `List<dynamic>`/`List<object>` (and lose type safety)
- Probably more options that I cannot think of right now